# Toggle hotspot programmatically in android N

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, hotspot

I'm using android N and I'm trying to turn on wifi hotspot when the user opens the application. I was able to turn on the hotspot using the code that I mentioned below but other mobiles are not able to connect to this network, they stuck at Obtaining IP address.

### Functionality

```
public void changeStateWifiAp(boolean activated) {
    Method method;
    try {
        method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, Boolean.TYPE);
        method.invoke(wifiManager, wifiConfiguration, activated);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```